# Local/global maximum

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

Suppose I have the following function $f(x)=x^2(1-x^2)$. Now this function has maxima at $\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and they are equal. Is this maximum absolute or relative? It is absolute right?

Comment: This function is of degree $4$, so it will have $3$ critical points: $0$ and $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$. It tends to negative infinity as $x$ goes to plus or minus infinity.

Comment: Yes those are global maxima

Comment: The critical points at $\pm\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ are global minima.

Comment: Ah yes sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2(1-x^2)$.

Note that $f$ is an even function, so has $y$-axis symmetry. Thus, it suffices to analyze the behavior of $f$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Computing $f'(x)$, we get $f'(x)=2x(1-2x^2)$.

- On the interval $(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, we have $f'(x) > 0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing.

  On the interval $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\infty)$, we have $f'(x) < 0$, so $f$ is strictly decreasing.

It follows that on the interval $[0,\infty)$, $f$ achieves a global maximum at $x={\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}$.

By symmetry, $f$ also achieves a global maximum at $x=-\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, write $f(x)=\frac14-(\frac12-x^2)^2$.  As squares are non-negative, it is easier to see why the maximum is when $x^2=\frac12$ and why it is global.